# SQL Server result as Json Array

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

I need to perform a query that outputs a Json array.

SQL Server has the function `FOR JSON PATH;` but the output would be:

```
[{"key_1":"value_1","key_2":"value_2"},{"key_1":"value_3","key_2":"value_4"}]
```

But the output I need is:

```
{ "key_1": ["value_1","value_3"],
  "key_2": ["value_2","value_4"]
}
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Add `, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` after `FOR JSON PATH`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/remove-square-brackets-from-json-without-array-wrapper-option?view=sql-server-ver15

UPDATE:

This isn't the prettiest solution, but it works. I tried to recreate some data based on the original format of your output. So the answer is based on that assumption.

```sql
-- Test data (based on what I could figure out from your question)
CREATE TABLE dbo.jsonvalues
(
    key_1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,key_2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.jsonvalues
(
    key_1
    ,key_2
)
VALUES
(
    N'value_1'
    ,N'value_2'
)
,(
    N'value_3'
    ,N'value_4'
);
```

To get the data in the right format you would first have to unpivot the data (or store it differently). Then you can create an array in the output by using a sub-query in the `SELECT`.

```sql
SELECT
    *
INTO
    #newformat
FROM
    dbo.jsonvalues AS J
UNPIVOT
    (
        vals FOR keys IN (key_1, key_2)
    ) AS u;

SELECT
    N.keys
    ,(SELECT N2.vals FROM #newformat AS N2 WHERE N2.keys = N.keys FOR JSON AUTO) AS vals
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            keys
        FROM
            #newformat
    ) AS N
FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
    "keys":"key_1","vals":[{"vals":"value_1"},{"vals":"value_3"}]
},
{
    "keys":"key_2","vals":[{"vals":"value_2"},{"vals":"value_4"}]
}
```

This won't give you exactly what you want but is the closest I could get without starting to do some manual tweaking. I included the tweaks I did below to get to your requested output format. Just be warned that it is brittle and might need additional tweaks for your data.

```sql
SELECT
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((
    SELECT
        N.keys
        ,(SELECT N2.vals FROM #newformat AS N2 WHERE N2.keys = N.keys FOR JSON AUTO) AS vals
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT
             keys
         FROM
             #newformat
        ) AS N
    FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    ),'"keys":',''),'"vals"',''),',:',':'),'},{:',','),'{:',''),'}]}',']');
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
    "key_1":["value_1","value_3"]
    ,"key_2":["value_2","value_4"]
}
```

Comment: But can i aggregate all values with the key ? 

```(Example: "key_1": ["value_1","value_3"])```

Comment: Yes, you can. But it is very messy. See my updated answer for an example of how it could be done.